# How do I add a blank <option> element to a <option> list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, input

**Situation:**

I have an `option` list like

```
<select class="database-column-name" name="caseid">
     <option value="1">1</option> 
     <option value="2">1</option> 
     <option value="3">1</option> 
</select>
```

and by default there is no `option` selected, but when you select an `option` you can't go back to selecting none again! This messes up the user experience of my page because I need the user to be able to selected no option at all.

**Question:**

Is there a hack to get around this?

Comment: Add an option with an empty value (or invalid like -1). Make sure to handle the new values where you process the form. Give the new option meaningful text like "None". Alternatively you van use javascript to set `selectedIndex` to -1. This will remove the select.

Answer (score 1):

Is as simple as this

```
<select class="database-column-name" name="caseid">
<option value=" ">--Select--</option> 
     <option value="1">1</option> 
     <option value="2">1</option> 
     <option value="3">1</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select.database-column-name option").prop("selected", false);
```

You could have a "clear selection" button or something fire this code.

Answer (score -1):

The preceding answer is a really good choice. The only recommendation that I would add to it is to make the value for the first item a "0"(zero), which allows your post-processing code to look for a specific value to ensure "no selection". Granted, you can look for " ", but that's easy to confuse with "".

```
<select class="database-column-name" name="caseid">
<option value="0">--Select--</option> 
<option value="1">1</option> 
<option value="2">1</option> 
<option value="3">1</option>
```

If you want to have an actual blank show, rather than a phrase like "--Select--" then simply replace the "--Select--" text with a space.

```
<html>
<body>
<select class="database-column-name" name="caseid">
<option value="0"> </option>
<option value="1">option 1</option>
<option value="2">option 2</option>
<option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>
```

The "value" portion is not displayed and is present to simplify code-based analysis of the selected option. In this case, a value of "0" would mean that no option has been selected.

Comment: Yes, I agree, "0" is a value, that was the idea behind using it. Perhaps I misunderstood your point?